How to calculates changes in position with perpendicular tracking wheels and a orientation sensor by assuming movement in arcs?
I want to use a system of odometry to find where my robot is at all times by finding the displacement of the robot every 10 ms.  To do this I am using a vertical tracking wheel that tracks when the robot is moving forward or backward in relation to the robot, a horizontal tracking wheel that tracks when the robot is moving side to side in relation to the robot and a orientation sensor that gives the orientation of the robot at all times (the orientation sensor has no bounds).  I use vertical_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131 to get how much the vertical tracking wheel has moved (converted to inches), horizontal_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131 to get how much the horizontal tracking wheel has moved (converted to inches), and imu.get_rotation() * M_PI / 180 to get the current orientation in radians.
The vertical tracking wheel is offset from the center by -10 inches and the horizontal by 4.21875 inches.  I use C++.
I tried calculating the movements by calculating the wheels movements with arcs.  I expected that the numbers would be +- .1 - .5 inches off.  When I move straight in any direction my code works very well but when I turn my robot any every if off by multiple inches.  For example I drove 24 inches forward and my robot said I was a at x = 24.03 and y = .05 but when I turned one rotation making sure to stay on the circle's path the entire time and then moved back to the starting point I got x = .49 and y = -4.45.  This was my code.
I start by finding the changes in the movement of each wheel and the orientation sensor.  **This part works.
**
double total_wheel_movement_vertical = vertical_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131;
double total_wheel_movement_horizontal = horizontal_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131;
double theta = imu.get_rotation() * M_PI / 180;

//finds changes in the tracking wheel's movement and orientation of the robot
double delta_wheel_movement_vertical = total_wheel_movement_vertical - previous_total_wheel_movement_vertical;
double delta_wheel_movement_horizontal = total_wheel_movement_horizontal - previous_total_wheel_movement_horizontal;
double delta_theta = theta - previous_theta;

//updates previous values for the next calculations
previous_total_wheel_movement_vertical = total_wheel_movement_vertical;
previous_total_wheel_movement_horizontal = total_wheel_movement_horizontal;
previous_theta = theta;

Then, I calculate the x and y movements relative to the robot by assuming the robot has moved in a arc and use each wheel's arc's chord length or if the robot hasn't turned I calculate the movement as lines.
        //calculates the chord length of the arc / the length of the movement of the tracking center
        if (fabs(delta_theta) != 0) {
            delta_local_y = 2 * sin(delta_theta / 2) * (delta_wheel_movement_vertical / delta_theta + tracking_wheel_offset_vertical);
            delta_local_x = 2 * sin(delta_theta / 2) * (delta_wheel_movement_horizontal / delta_theta + tracking_wheel_offset_horizontal);
        } else {
            delta_local_y = delta_wheel_movement_vertical;
            delta_local_x = delta_wheel_movement_horizontal;
        }

Then, I calculate the average angle of the arcs.  This will be what I use as the angle for the final calculation.
        double average_theta = previous_theta - delta_theta / 2;

Finally, I put the average angle of the arc's and each arc's length into a formula that finds the endpoint of two perpendicular lines and add it to the starting global position to find the new global position.
        x += delta_local_y * cos(average_theta) - delta_local_x * sin(average_theta);
        y += delta_local_y * sin(average_theta) + delta_local_x * cos(average_theta);

This is all of my code for completeness.
//sets tracking wheel constants
const double tracking_wheel_offset_vertical = -10; //offset of tracking wheels from the tracking center of the robot in inches
const double tracking_wheel_offset_horizontal = 4.21875; //offset of tracking wheels from the tracking center of the robot in inches

//sets autonomous starting values
double x = 0; //global x position
double y = 0; //global y position
double delta_local_y = 0; //vertical chord length of the arc / movement of the tracking center
double delta_local_x = 0; //horizontal chord length of the arc / movement of the tracking center

//function to update the robot's estimated position
void update_pose() {
    //sets previous values to current values for intial calculations
    double previous_total_wheel_movement_horizontal = horizontal_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131;
    double previous_total_wheel_movement_vertical = vertical_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131;
    double previous_theta = imu.get_rotation() * M_PI / 180;

    while (true) {
        //delays the start of each cycle to save computing resources
        pros::delay(10);

        //gets current values of the tracking wheel in inches and the orientation of the robot in radians
        double total_wheel_movement_vertical = vertical_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131;
        double total_wheel_movement_horizontal = horizontal_rotation_sensor.get_position() / 5729.57795131;
        double theta = imu.get_rotation() * M_PI / 180;

        //finds changes in the tracking wheel's movement and orientation of the robot
        double delta_wheel_movement_vertical = total_wheel_movement_vertical - previous_total_wheel_movement_vertical;
        double delta_wheel_movement_horizontal = total_wheel_movement_horizontal - previous_total_wheel_movement_horizontal;
        double delta_theta = theta - previous_theta;

        //updates previous values for the next calculations
        previous_total_wheel_movement_vertical = total_wheel_movement_vertical;
        previous_total_wheel_movement_horizontal = total_wheel_movement_horizontal;
        previous_theta = theta;

        //calculates the chord length of the arc / the length of the movement of the tracking center
        if (fabs(delta_theta) != 0) {
            delta_local_y = 2 * sin(delta_theta / 2) * (delta_wheel_movement_vertical / delta_theta + tracking_wheel_offset_vertical);
            delta_local_x = 2 * sin(delta_theta / 2) * (delta_wheel_movement_horizontal / delta_theta + tracking_wheel_offset_horizontal);
        } else {
            delta_local_y = delta_wheel_movement_vertical;
            delta_local_x = delta_wheel_movement_horizontal;
        }

        //calculates the angle of the chord of the arc / which direction the tracking center moved
        double average_theta = previous_theta - delta_theta / 2;

        //changes in the global position based on the chord's length and angle / the direction and distance the tracking center moved
        x += delta_local_y * cos(average_theta) - delta_local_x * sin(average_theta);
        y += delta_local_y * sin(average_theta) + delta_local_x * cos(average_theta);

        //prints tracking and debuging values to screen
        pros::lcd::print(0, "X: %f", x);
        pros::lcd::print(1, "Y: %f", y);
        pros::lcd::print(2, "Theta: %f", theta * 180 / M_PI);
        pros::lcd::print(3, "Total Local X Movement: %f", total_wheel_movement_horizontal);
        pros::lcd::print(4, "Total Local Y Movement: %f", total_wheel_movement_vertical);
    }
}```


  [1]: http://thepilons.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Tracking.pdf


You need to know exactly where your robots actual axis of rotation is in relation to the tracking wheels. Having them at unequal offset distances makes your calculations  more difficult. Try movement smaller arcs like 45 degrees and 90 degrees and see if you can isolate the fault to one or other of the rotation sensors. Starting in x and going to +y then x to -y and vice versa. Then you can identify any quadrant trig errors.

I figured out that the problem was that I had configured my offsets to a corner on my robot as I had misinterpreted a paragraph in a position tracking paper by E-Bots πlons  (IDK how to add links). I though it was proving that where the tracking center was didn't matter but instead it proved that you only need to know the perpendicular length to the tracking center.  Thanks to Martin Brown for making me look back through the paper again.
